# How to test withTimeout wrapped inside of coroutineScope() with runTest, Kotlin coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutinescope, coroutines-testing

My code uses `async()` call wrapped with `withTimeoutOrNull()`, in order to cancel waiting (not the call itself) after a set amount of time, like so:

```
val deferredResult: Deferred<Boolean?>? = null

suspend fun fetchData(waitForDuration: Duration): Boolean? = coroutineScope {
    ...

    val deferredResult = async {
        // Some long running work
    }
    withTimeoutOrNull(waitForDuration) {
        deferredResult.await()
    }

    ...
}
```

This works as expected and returns `null` after timeout has elapsed, without canceling the network call.

However, when I try to cover this with a unit test, to check that in case of timeout waiting stops after X minutes and returns `null`, I run into a (for me) unexpected behaviour because of the `coroutineScope()` used by the `fetchData()` function.

Here is the stripped down version of the test method that fails. (Below is a version of the test method that passes, the only difference being `coroutineScope`)

```
@Test
fun `FAIL test that method stops await after timeout, without canceling call`() = runTest {
        val deferredFirstCallResult = coroutineScope {
            async {
                delay(2.minutes)
            }
        }
        withTimeoutOrNull(1.minutes) {
            deferredFirstCallResult.await()
        }

        // This FAILS. Current time has already advanced to 2.minutes
        assertEquals(1.minutes, currentTime.milliseconds)
        // ... check that result is null etc

        advanceUntilIdle()
        assertEquals(2.minutes, currentTime.milliseconds)
}
```

Here is the one without `coroutineScope()`:

```
@Test
fun `PASS test that method stops await after timeout, without canceling call`() = runTest {
        val deferredFirstCallResult = async {
            delay(2.minutes)
        }
        withTimeoutOrNull(1.minutes) {
            deferredFirstCallResult.await()
        }

        // This is okay. Current time is 1.minutes
        assertEquals(1.minutes, currentTime.milliseconds)
        // ... check that result is null etc

        advanceUntilIdle()
        assertEquals(2.minutes, currentTime.milliseconds)
}
```

What am I missing here and is there a way to keep `coroutineScope()` in the method and check in the test that method really returns after timeout has elapsed?

Comment: `coroutineScope` always waits for all its child coroutines to complete before continuing. What is the reason you want to use it in your test?